# Is breaking a company bond suicidal for your career?

Tags: job-offer, new-job, contracts, india, fresher

If I join this company right after graduation I would have to sign a bond and pay a fixed amount to be deposited as security measure in case I leave the company before 2 years!

They say they will be providing training and investing time and effort hence these measures. I am not sure how much training I will actually be receiving, however money is not the issue - time is.

I am thinking of going for Post Graduation courses in about a year, which may or may not impact my ability to continue at this company. However, HR is telling me that it would be **"suicidal"** for anyone's career if they broke this bond.

I have another offer from a company which also requires I sign/pay a bond, but for a period of only 6 months. Unfortunately I am not particularly interested in working for this company.

As of now I want to sign with the former company as they are offering good experience and a better salary than the latter. However I would like to leave the company if I get admitted for a PG Course within a year.

Would breaking the bond truly have disastrous consequences for my career?

Comment: Any reason why you can't study part time, or wait another year?

Comment: I think the program I will join is very rigorous and obviously will be away from where I work. Waiting another year will be a bad decision since it will be late and I may not  get the right college .

Comment: @PhilipKendall How is it pushing this question into off topic territory ? I just want to consider the factor of signing a bond as a fresher is it worth ?

Comment: Santosh - I'd have to agree with Philip. The question was ok, but now it is too broad/subjective

Comment: @RoryAlsop Ok I have removed the EDIT still I am looking for some better answer/advice as I am still confused.

Comment: Why would you want to enter into an agreement that you intend to break? Not a very nice attitude to life. Does your partner know you have this behaviour?

Comment: @EdHeal Santosh has not entered into this agreement yet.  It is definitely ethical and wise to try to fully understand the terms and conditions of an agreement before entering into it.

Comment: @EdHeal I want to get the job because finding another job like this on my own can be very hard after graduation is done and I leave the college. I would want to break it because I want to go for further studies but this can or cannot happen because of the main factor like how well I perform in the entrance exam comes into play .

Comment: @emory - I was trying to suggest that it is not a good idea to enter into a contract that you intend to break. Especially when your career is involved.

Comment: @Santosh - Why not postpone the studies for a year? Not a lot of time. Also leave your first job on good terms - that is very important in your time of life

Comment: I really do not understand this as a practical matter.  Does Santos lose the bond if the company fires him? If they fire him for no good reason? (You have served admirably 1 year, 364 days, but today we are firing you - pay us back the bond).  If them firing him means he does not have to pay back the bond, can he just not show up or do an incredibly poor job - just do the best you can given that the majority of your attention is focused elsewhere?

Comment: Regardless of the "bond", joining a company in a full-time position fresh out of college with the intention of leaving after only 1 year is a very disrespectful thing to do. It's common, sure, but still disrespectful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm no lawyer, and can't advise you from a legal point of view. From a ***professional*** POV, however, I can tell you that your reputation goes a long way.

If this company is going to keep track of the fact that you jumped ship, and broke your bond, then they might share that information later with potential employers calling for a reference - and since this is your first job, and your only industry experience, future employers will definitely want a reference.

Furthermore, if you sign that you'll be leaving in 2 years, and other companies in the area are aware of this policy, but see on your resume that you left after ***one*** they might jump to their own conclusions regarding how reliable you are.

At the end of the day, however, this is your decision to make. I can guarantee you that somewhere, somehow, you will get another job in the industry. In future interviews you can simply say that you had pressing family matters which cause you to have to break your bond, etc.

In other words, their threats might work if they are asked for a reference, and they themselves might never hire you again, however once you gain more experience you'll be fine.

Answer (score 3):

> However, HR is telling me that it would be "suicidal" for anyone's career if they broke this bond.

I wouldn't expect HR to say anything else. They don't want people entering the bond lightly.

Two years is a long time and many things can happen in the meantime. The bond is a financial incentive for you not to leave the job. They put the training in, they expect to get X number of years out of you. Besides that, the standard [advice for job hopping](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-hopping) applies.

I don't look kindly upon such schemes unless the training provided is niche and world-renowned, and therefore worth the two-year commitment, because employers are *expected* to train their employees. Then again I see where they're coming from.

No, it won't be suicidal, but it's a bad move regardless. It'll be something you'll have to explain to future interviews, something [AndreiROM explores nicely in his answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/63085/9549). It will also leave you with some financial burden, which can affect your next job search indirectly (cutting down how many months you can live off of your savings, going to an interview somewhere far away, being unable to buy a new suit, etc). Those are the concerns of the pennyless jobseeker, but your mileage will of course vary.